# In Swift's Unsafe API, how can I allocate memory and fail with error but without crash when asking for too much?

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

In Swift's Unsafe API (on iOS), this

```
let p = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 10_000_000_000, alignment: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)
```

crashes, whereas C's malloc returns a nullptr when there is not sufficient memory available. So in C, one can then gracefully ask for less memory whereas with this Swift Unsafe API one just crashes.
While I do not want to allocate 10 GiB (this is just for demonstration)  I am still annoyed that there seems to be no mechanism to fail gracefully when allocating memory with that Swift Unsafe API and asking for too much. I feel it is not my job to know how much is too much and there should be an error message that tells me when I ask for too much. How could I do this with the Swift Unsafe API? Or should I just forget it and use C to write my manual memory allocator?

Comment: You can use `malloc` in Swift too, and that returns `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`. It's just less "Swifty".

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint!  In fact, aligned_alloc seems to be what I am looking for where one can in addition request a certain alignment!